# Access Observable values and assign to a collection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am receiving an Observable back from an Angular service and I can see the data coming back from the service when it resolves using `.subscribe`

```
returnedObservable$.subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    return res;
]);
```

I have tried assigning this to an Object inside of the `.subscribe` but the assignment isn't happening.

```
let newObj = {};
returnedObservable$.subscribe(res => newObj = res);
```

How can I make this assignment to get the values out of the Observable?

The first time it tries to access the response the result is `null` but eventually resolves.

The `console.log(res)` looks like this:

```
{
    itemList: [
        { id: 1, name: Steve },
        { id: 2, name: Bob },
        { id: 3, name: Tim }        
    ]
}
```

Comment: I assume the problem is that you are trying to use newObj right after the subscribe line. That won't work. Observables are (generally) asynchronous. You need to do whatever you wanna do with the data *in* the subscribe.

Comment: That does make sense since the first time it returns `null`. So far I have only tried to do an assignment and then tried to print out the Object or Array. My end goal is to access that nested array and loop through it with an `ngFor` in the DOM. Can you recommend a way to do that?

Comment: Just assign the result to a class member inside subscribe and make sure to safe-guard the ngFor with an ngIf as it will temporarily not be set (since it's async). Alternatively, assign the observable itself to a class member and use the async pipe. All of this is covered in the Angular ToH guide.

Comment: ` but the assignment isn't happening.` - are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
let newObj = {};
returnedObservable$.subscribe(res => {newObj = res}).add(()=>
{ 
   //Use your object here
   console.log(newObj);
});
```